# Error deploy azure Web App for cotainers

Tags: azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I have build an flask app image, and can be used in local. But When I deploy it to web app, the web site can't be loaded. I have followed the doc that use azure-cli to deploy. Also trying deploy by azure portal. By the azure-cli, no code can be found and the site is the initial page. By portal, the web site is always reloaded and can't be loaded. I don't know where is the problem.

The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV HOME /root

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
git \
bash \
curl \
lsb-release
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install apt-transport-https


RUN pip3 install pip --upgrade

# RUN ["/bin/bash","-c", "AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)"]
# to-do: 下一步读取不了这一步的环境变量，先写 xenial 应急吧
RUN ["/bin/bash","-c", "echo 'deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli/ xenial main' | \
 tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/azure-cli.list"]
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c","apt-key adv --keyserver packages.microsoft.com --recv-keys 52E16F86FEE04B979B07E28DB02C46DF417A0893"]
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c","curl -L  https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -"]

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install azure-cli
RUN az aks install-cli


ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt



# CMD ["python3", "upload.py"]
CMD ["gunicorn", "upload:app",  "-c", "gunicorn.conf.py"]
```

The end of `upload.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The `gunicorn.conf.py`:

```
workers = 5    
worker_class = "gevent"  
bind = "0.0.0.0:80"
```

Comment: In this scenario, the first thing we need to do is determine whether it is a deployment issue or a runtime issue: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-vs-runtime-issues.

Comment: What's the doc are you following? What's the web.config file?

Comment: [Use a custom Docker image for Web App for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image)